# Why do we prefix the implementation name of an interface and not suffix it?

Tags: java, interface, naming-conventions

I get, that we read from left to right and
`ApacheConfigFileHandler implements ConfigFileHandler`
sounds better than
`ConfigFileHandlerApache implements ConfigFileHandler`
when spoken.

But when I search a class, I usually know the Interface I'm looking for and usually dont know the exact implemenation name.
I know that I'm looking for a `ConfigFileHandler`, but I might not know that the Implemenation name I'm looking for is 'Apache'.
So in terms of code completion, with the suffix approach, I could search for `ConfigFileHandler` and it would then suggest me all implementations of a `ConfigFileHandler`, including the `AppacheConfigFileHandler`.

The advantage of the suffix approach becomes even more clear, when the inheritance hierarchy is bigger:
Let's say I have
`FastApacheConfigFileHandler extends ApacheConfigFileHandler`
which would be
`ConfigFileHandlerApacheFast extends ConfigFileHandlerApache`
 with the suffix approach.

I know I'm searching for a `ConfigFileHandler` so I type `ConfigFileHandler`, then I see Apache and think "yeah, I remember the class I'm searching for is a `AppacheConfigFileHandler`", so I continue typing until `ConfigFileHandlerApache` and see all extensions/ implementations of `AppacheConfigFileHandler` and finally find my `FastApacheConfigFileHandler` aka `ConfigFileHandlerApacheFast`.

Is there anything wrong with the implementation name suffix approach (except it does not sound that nice when spoken)?
If yes, what is wrong is it? 
If no, why hasn't this approach become the standard?

**edit**:
Another Point: It makes more sense to me, that, when I'm reading a class name (from left to right), it becomes more specific the further I read the name and does not start with the most detail.

One example for that: When im reading the first word Fast from `FastApacheConfigFileHandler`, I have no idea what im dealing with, then I'm reading FastApache, still not much of an idea, then im reading `FastApacheConfigFileHandler`, than I know exactly what im dealing with. Vs when I read `ConfigFileHandler` first, I kinda know what im dealing with and get more details, the further I read the classname.

Comment: Unfortunately I suspect this isn't really a great fit for StackOverflow, so it's likely to be closed, as it's purely a matter of opinion. If you're working on your own, go ahead and use whatever convention works best for you; if you're in a team, see if a majority of your teammates would want to make that change. In both cases, don't be surprised if other people encountering your code think it's odd, as it differs from the standard convention.

Comment: For your specific point, IntelliJ will offer autocomplete suggestions based on names that match any part of the text you're typing, not just the start, so it would suggest both of your examples when you started typing "Conf..." (or, indeed, "Fil..." or "Handl..." or "Apac...").

Comment: Not all implementations/extensions follow a naming convention like that, so using that to find implementations/extensions will make you miss out on some. E.g. an implementation on `Queue` is `LinkedList`. The word "Queue" doesn't appear in the implementing class name. If you want to find implementations/extensions, you should use the features of you IDE to find them.

Comment: There is no science behind it. Just common sense. It's all about how we approach real world events/people/stuff.

Comment: I a shell you can simply invoke `ls *ConfigFileHandler.java` (or `dir *ConfigFileHandler.java` in the Windows command prompt) to get a list of all implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The most important reason I can see, is that it completely breaks with both standard *Java naming conventions* and *English language semantics*. In doing so, it violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Taking this approach to its natural conclusion, class names become completely intractable.

Applying it to the `java.util` package:

- Should you use a [`ListArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or a [`ListLinked`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)?
- What would a [`TokenizerString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) be?
- Is a [`MapTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) a tree or a map? Is a [`TaskTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) a timer or a task?
- Is a [`LoaderService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) a service? What about an [`ErrorConfigurationService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceConfigurationError.html)?
- Etc.

Comment: The principle of least astonishment is a good argument against using the postfix approach now in a project, when the whole world is using the prefix approach. But this is always violated, when criticizing a widely used convention. The real question for me is, why is the postfix approach so much worse then the prefix approach,** regardless what's the standard right now**. When the whole world would use the postfix approach, it would be called ListArray and ListLinked, MapTree would be a map without any confusion. ServiceLoader and probably remain the same, since it does not impl service.

Comment: The violation of natural language semantics is the only argument I see against the prefix notation (when neglecting whats the standard right now). And I already mentioned that. Note that ConfigFileHandler did not become HandlerConfigFile or somthing, because it is all about implementation names and not about switching it all around. So StringTokenizer would probably remain the same. And in my opinion the pro of easier finding the implementations outweighs the con of the violation of the natural language semantics.

Comment: I don't know what IDE you use, but mine (IntelliJ) will perfectly show prefixed class names in its autocomplete suggestions. And browsing the type hierarchy will show me all implementations of an interface.

Comment: I'm also using IntelliJ, and I also find my Classes like that, but still a convention should not rely on that feature in my opinion. And also: it makes more sense to me, that,  when I'm reading a class name (from left to right), it becomes more specific the further I read the name and does not start with the most detail.

Comment: One example for that: When im reading the first word Fast from FastApacheConfigFileHandler, I have no idea what im dealing with, then I'm reading FastApache, still not much of an idea, then im reading FastApacheConfigFileHandler, than I know exactly what im dealing with. Vs when I read ConfigFileHandler first, I kinda know what im dealing with and get more and more an idea, the further I read.

Comment: I've updated the question, since that point differs alot from my previous argument for the prefix approach.

Comment: Listen, your question was "why is it never used?". Instead of voting to close the question as primarily opinion-based, I presented you the two main reasons that I saw for that. If you want to break with convention, feel free to do so. And if someone else has to ever touch your code, carefully explain your reasoning and hope for their understanding as to why your naming scheme is different from every other library out there.

Comment: yeah you are right, thats why I updated the question. Thanks for your input.